# Connection php files above or below the root?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, root

Just so I have this right...

Above the root (where the word here is) would be...

```
         here/public/allfiles.php
```

Below the root (where the word here is) would be....

```
         public/here/allfiles.php
```

Ok, so...

I have been trying to place the php connection file ABOVE the root but of course I have been having problems with that for obvious reasons, being that anything ABOVE the root directory is not accessible

So my question is this...

Is it considered safe for the purposes of creating a secure php website by placing the connection.php folder (for mysql connections etc) BELOW the root and placing a htaccess file within that folder to prevent peeps viewing it

Comment: Unless your server is misconfigured and renders `.php` files as plain text file, it doesn’t quite matter.

Comment: You can include php from above the web accessible folder with `../some_other_php_in_here` though you might have problems depending on how much access you have on your server.